# Pushing in list

Tags: lisp

What I want to do is to repeteadly take an element from a list and if it respects the condition,I'll append it to a new list and to keep the list format.How do I do the appending part?
I'm getting the element with `nth` and I've tried several variants of `push` but I'm not getting where I want.

For example I do `(setq a 2)`
I want now to push 4 and later 8.How do I put the element in there and keep the list format?

Comment: You need more examples of what you want to do, in terms of before and after. Right now your question is just vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to push, use [`push`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm):

```
(defparameter *a* ())
(push 1 *a*)
*a* ==> (1)
(push 2 *a*)
*a* ==> (2 1)
```

For your specific task:

```
(dolist (x *old-list*)
  (when (my-test-p x)
    (push x *new-list*)))
(setq *new-list* (nreverse *new-list*))
```

Actually, this can be done with a standard library function [`remove-if-not`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm):

```
(setq *new-list* (remove-if-not #'my-test-p *old-list*))
```

or, if you prefer

```
(setq *new-list* (remove-if (complement #'my-test-p) *old-list*))
```